# SQL - Add consecutive column values when they are between a given value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am somewhat new to SQL and need some help. Thanks in advance!

I have a table similar to the one below in MS SQL Server 2014.

```
AcctID  DateScanned
16      2015-12-09 13:24:19.000
16      2015-12-09 13:24:43.000
16      2015-12-09 13:25:49.000
16      2016-02-10 11:19:58.000
16      2016-02-10 11:20:26.000
16      2016-02-20 10:18:54.000
16      2016-02-20 10:18:56.000
16      2016-02-20 10:18:58.000
16      2016-05-23 11:39:47.000
16      2016-06-08 13:02:11.000
16      2016-08-31 20:02:10.000
16      2016-09-14 15:30:40.000
16      2016-09-14 15:31:31.000
```

I've been able to use a join to calculate the time (in seconds) between the current scan and the next scan (TimeDiff).

```
SELECT a.AcctID, a.DateScanned, MIN(b.DateScanned) AS NextScan
        , DATEDIFF(SECOND,a.DateScanned, MIN(b.DateScanned)) AS TimeDiff, 
FROM myTable a
    LEFT JOIN myTable b
        ON a.AcctID = b.AcctID AND a.DateScanned < b.DateScanned
GROUP BY a.AcctID, a.DateScanned



AcctID  DateScanned                NextScan                  TimeDiff
16      2015-12-09 13:24:19.000    2015-12-09 13:24:43.000   24
16      2015-12-09 13:24:43.000    2015-12-09 13:25:49.000   66
16      2015-12-09 13:25:49.000    2016-02-10 11:19:58.000   5435649
16      2016-02-10 11:19:58.000    2016-02-10 11:20:26.000   28
16      2016-02-10 11:20:26.000    2016-02-20 10:18:54.000   860308
16      2016-02-20 10:18:54.000    2016-02-20 10:18:56.000   2
16      2016-02-20 10:18:56.000    2016-02-20 10:18:58.000   2
16      2016-02-20 10:18:58.000    2016-05-23 11:39:47.000   8040049
16      2016-05-23 11:39:47.000    2016-06-08 13:02:11.000   1387344
16      2016-06-08 13:02:11.000    2016-08-31 20:02:10.000   7282799
16      2016-08-31 20:02:10.000    2016-09-14 15:30:40.000   1193310
16      2016-09-14 15:30:40.000    2016-09-14 15:31:31.000   51
16      2016-09-14 15:31:31.000    NULL                      NULL
```

I need to add the TimeDiff values together for consecutive rows that have TimeDiff <= 900 and display the result with the first DateScanned of that group. For this example, I would see:

```
AcctID  DateScanned                Result
16      2015-12-09 13:24:19.000    90
16      2016-02-10 11:19:58.000    28
16      2016-02-20 10:18:54.000    4
16      2016-09-14 15:30:40.000    51
```

Thanks again for any help.

Comment: Could you paste your query here?

Comment: we dont have time to recreate your data and do you first query PASTE YOUR FIRST STEP

Comment: I've added the query. Thanks

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: try using Lead function if using SQL server 2012

Comment: Using Sql Server 2014

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to classify consecutive rows into groups.

1 - Get the datediff of current and next row's datescanned and check if the value is <=900 and assign 1 to all such rows and 0 to the remaining ones.

2 - Then classify the rows into groups using the row_number() function.

3 - Select the rows from cte whose calculated diff_column <=900 per each group.

4 - Finally get the first date of such groups and the max running total (<=900) of those groups.

```
with grps as (
    select *, 
    row_number() over(partition by acctid order by datescanned)
    - row_number() over(partition by acctid,col order by datescanned) grp
    from 
    (select *, 
     datediff(second,datescanned,lead(datescanned) over(partition by acctid order by datescanned)) as diff_column,
     case when datediff(second,datescanned,lead(datescanned) over(partition by acctid order by datescanned)) <=900 then 1 else 0 end col
     from tablename) t
    ) 
select distinct acctid,
min(datescanned) over(partition by acctid,grp) first_date,
max(grp_tot) over(partition by acctid,grp) grp_total
from (select *
      ,sum(diff_column) over(partition by acctid,grp order by datescanned) grp_tot
      from grps 
      where diff_column <= 900
      ) x 
where grp_tot <=900
```

[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/DIAPNA25226)

Comment: Thanks so much! This is great.

Comment: FYI, I added the "RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING" argument in the over clause for grp_tot. Otherwise I get a running total for grp_tot and the SELECT DISTINCT picks up all the datescanned's for each group instead of the min(datescanned)

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Scans') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Scans;
CREATE TABLE #Scans (AcctID INT, DateScanned DATETIME);

INSERT #Scans VALUES
(16,'2015-12-09 13:24:19.000'),
(16,'2015-12-09 13:24:43.000'),
(16,'2015-12-09 13:25:49.000'),
(16,'2016-02-10 11:19:58.000'),
(16,'2016-02-10 11:20:26.000'),
(16,'2016-02-20 10:18:54.000'),
(16,'2016-02-20 10:18:56.000'),
(16,'2016-02-20 10:18:58.000'),
(16,'2016-05-23 11:39:47.000'),
(16,'2016-06-08 13:02:11.000'),
(16,'2016-08-31 20:02:10.000'),
(16,'2016-09-14 15:30:40.000'),
(16,'2016-09-14 15:31:31.000');

WITH Baseline AS
(
    SELECT AcctID,
        DateScanned,
        LEAD(DateScanned) OVER (PARTITION BY AcctID ORDER BY DateScanned) AS NextScan,
        CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, DateScanned, LEAD(DateScanned) OVER (PARTITION BY AcctID ORDER BY DateScanned)) <= 900 
                THEN 1 
            ELSE 
                0 
        END AS ValidRecord
    FROM #Scans s
), CreateGroups AS
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AcctID ORDER BY DateScanned) - 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AcctID, ValidRecord ORDER BY DateScanned) AS GroupID
    FROM Baseline
)
SELECT AcctID,
    MIN(DateScanned) AS DateScanned,
    DATEDIFF(SECOND,MIN(DateScanned),MAX(NextScan)) AS [Result]
FROM CreateGroups
WHERE ValidRecord = 1
GROUP BY AcctID, GroupID
```

Comment: @ti034 This is just another way to write vkp answer. I did not want to edit their answer since they have a demo and it is such and eloquent solution, but it had not been accepted so I figured you may have had a hard time following the logic, but vkp's answer should be the accepted solution.

Comment: I was just able to take a look at it quickly this morning. I will be trying it out this afternoon. Thanks Eric!